# Highcharts marker for single point won't display

Tags: highcharts

I loop over the data and create a marker if the condition is met. All the points on the graph appear, but where the marker should be, because it met the condition, an empty point is displayed only and there is a gap in the chart.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (parseFloat(data[i][2]) >= 0.99999) {
          y_point = {
            'marker': {
              'enabled':true,
              'lineWidth': 3,
              'radius': 10,
              'symbol': 'triangle'
            },
            'y': parseFloat(data[i][1])
          }
        } else {
          y_point = parseFloat(data[i][1])
        }
        metricData.push([moment(data[i][0]).utc().unix() * 1000, y_point])
      }
      let chart = Highcharts.chart({
        time: {
          useUTC: false
        },
        chart: {
          zoomType: 'x',
          renderTo: this.$el,
          width: null,
          height: '60%'
        },
        title: {
          text: sample.metric_name
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            dataGrouping: false
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'spline',
          name: '% CPU',
          data: metricData,
          color: '#787878',
          turboThreshold: 0
        }],
        credits: false,
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your data as well, as it is more likely something wrong with the formatting there, than the chart setup.

Comment: That said, if that point falls outside the condition and you want to display the graph as "connected", then [`connectNulls`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls) will let you do that.

Comment: @ewolden it was how I was formatting my series data, an array of arrays with 1 point as a marker didn't work, when i switched it to an array of objects with a marker in 1 object it worked....